# delete icon in tabbar, sencha touch 2

Tags: model-view-controller, uitabbarcontroller, sencha-touch-2

I need a delete icon in my Sencha touch application and when it is clicked a confirm message should me displayed.This is what I required.But,it was taken to a new page.Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: What problem do you have with your code?  Can you provide what you already have?

Comment: title: 'Delete',
                    iconCls: 'delete',
                    cls: 'home',
      xtype:'formpanel'

  handler: function() {
   var del=confirm('Are you sure');

                 if(del)
{
  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'webservice/delete.php',
    method: 'GET',
   disableCaching: false,
       params: {

  id: Ext.getCmp('id2').getValue()

    }



      });

}

    }

Answer (score 0):

Why did you write `xtype: 'formpanel'`? It should be `xtype:'button'` instea. This works for me:

```
{
    title: 'Delete', 
    iconCls: 'delete', 
    cls: 'home', 
    xtype:'button' ,
    handler: function() 
    { 
        var del=confirm('Are you sure'); 
        if(del) { 
            console.log('confirm');
        } ;
    },
},
```